# Passing data between controllers with a service

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a single page form that I've decided to use Angular with as my jQuery implementation was quickly turning into spaghetti.

A primary feature of my form is that there are many separate inputs that will update the values of other inputs. Furthermore, each "input" might actually be multiple inputs (think an "inches" input with one `<select>` to determine whole inches, another `<select>` to determine fractional inches);

Right now I just want to be able to bind inputs in separate controllers so that when the value of something changes, I can see that update in another controller. Studying Angular, it looks like this is what using a service was made for.

Consider the following code (fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/qn7yb74d/ ):

```
<div ng-controller="AController">
    <select name="" id="" ng-model="selected.item">
        <option value="A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B">Option B</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div ng-controller="BController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myItem">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.service('myService', function(){
    this.selected = {
        item: 'A' // I want this to return the currently selected value - If val is changed to 'B', update the text input accordingly.
    }
});

myApp.controller('AController', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){
    $scope.selected.item = myService.selected.item;
}]);

myApp.controller('BController', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){
    $scope.myItem = myService.selected.item;
}]);
</script>
```

Simply put, I want any changes to `AController`'s `select` input to be reflected in `BController`'s `input` field. When you choose "Option A", I want the value ("A") to be shown in the input field.

**How do I update the model in a separate controller via a service when a value changes?**

Comment: Two questions. 1.) What exactly are you asking? Are you just looking to validate if this is a good idea? 2.) Why do you need to have each input represented by a different controller rather than using a single controller and binding to the same model property?

Comment: I am using separate controllers as the entire page needs to be modular so that (based on request params to the page) different components will load.

Comment: Sure I get that. Maybe it is just the example you have posted. Are the controllers going to be on the same page at once, or are they part of separate views?

Comment: Start by taking a look at ngChange: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange.  That will inform the controller of changes.  The controller should then inform your service of the change.  The service should then emit the change on rootScope.  Each controller would then be listening on $rootScope for the change. Read: http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/ and understand why $rootScope is you best option and don't skip the section on destroying your controller listeners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the `selected` object from `myService` into the scope for both controllers.

```
myApp.controller('AController', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){
    $scope.selected = myService.selected;
}]);

myApp.controller('BController', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){
    $scope.mySelected = myService.selected;
}]);
```

In every `AController` or `BController` `selected` or `mySelected` will refer to the same object. You can bind to this object under scopes created for either `AController` or `BController`.

```
<div ng-controller="AController">
    <select name="" id="" ng-model="selected.item">
        <option value="A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B">Option B</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div ng-controller="BController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="mySelected.item">
</div>
```

I've put this in a [complete working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17s5n20u/1/). Doing so required adding an `ng-app` and loading the module before `onLoad`.

Comment: I really had a strong feeling I was missing something simple. It didn't make sense that I had to go through all sorts of trouble to be able to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Looks to me like you were missing javascript closures! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the controllers are placed.

You may wanna have a look at this:
http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-communicating-between-controllers/

In one controller

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('foo',data)
```

In other controller

```
$rootScope.$on('foo', data)
```