# Pass dropdown value to other controller

Tags: angularjs

Firstly,i select all the category display in dropdown list,after that when user click the category the system will display all the list under the category.

```
<select ng-model="movielist" ng-options="cat as cat.name for cat in category">           
</select> //display all the category name

<p>Category Id: {{movielist.category_id}}</p> //will display the category id
```

**Question :** How can i pass the category id to other controller to produce the data?

[image][image]

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Do you want to stay on the same location or not? If so, why do you have two controllers? Where is your code?

Comment: Obviously you have to show more code and explain you problem in a more detailed way. 
From what i can understand so far you will have to read on these already asked questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115531/angular-js-pass-value-from-select-to-another-view
and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29497839/passing-data-between-controllers-with-a-service

Answer (score 0):

This is done for you automatically by using ng-model and ng-options. The variable namings are a little irritating to me, but the code itself should be working.

According to your namings:

1. `category` is the variable containing the list of all categories
2. A category has a `category_id` as property
3. `movielist` is the scope variable where your selection is written to.

So the code in your sample works when defining the content like this:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.category = [
    { "category_id": 0, "name": "zero" },
    { "category_id": 1, "name": "one" },
    { "category_id": 2, "name": "two" }
  ];
});
```

See a working demo here:

http://jsbin.com/xawesuhegu/edit?html,js,output

I would suggest to use some better naming, e.g. `categories` and `selectedCategory`.